# Is implementation of approximate dynamic maximal matching feasible?

Tags: algorithms, matching

I'm wondering if algorithms described in:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7782946/

http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4845/

easy to implement. They seem to mention the word "simple" but I'm not sure if this is all just theoretical play of "who's going to find the best $O$", or if this can be implemented in a sane amount of time (a couple of weeks).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good fit for this site.

Comment: I'm just wondering if polynomial time approximation schemes used here are implementable.

Comment: Have you tried implementing them?